# How to get Parent Element from json object using Vue

Tags: json, vue.js

I have some flattened out json data that I am working with and I'm having trouble accessing parts of it, so I'm hoping to use the elements I can access, then get their parent elements for display. I need to get the count of any arrays with multiple values and just display the value if there's only one, which I can do. Where I'm running into the issue is trying to display the parent(maybe not the best term?) value of the array.

For Example, if this is my json data:

```
{
  "Dogs": [
      {   
          "Name": "Gus",
          "Leashes": {
              "564": [
                  6
              ]
          }

      },
      {   
          "Name": "Jake",
          "Leashes": {
              "15775": [
                  "457",
                  "787",
                  "278"     
              ]
          }
      },
  ]
}
```

What can I do to access the "564" and "15775" values so I can display them in the left column of a table? I know the data is bad and should be standardized with an ID or something there, but it isn't, and there's nothing I can do about that until they fix their transform and get the data corrected. In this example, to get the length or to just display the data I need can use something like this (Please ignore the spans, this data will go in a table):

```
<template v-for="Dog in Dogs">
    <template v-for="Leash in Dog.Leashes">
        <span v-if="Leash.length <= '1'">{{ Leash[0] }}</span> (Gives me 
        the values which is good)
        <span v-if="Leash.length > '1'">{{ Leash.length }}</span> (Gives 
        me the count, also good)
    </template>
</template>
```

Where I am stuck is trying to get those parent values to display. I'm using a table and need the parent "IDs" for the left column and the values (which I can get) for the right column. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Trying to use a function or a vue instance for the data is slightly out of the question at the moment. I saw some complicated examples on how to do this, and I wasn't able to get them to work. is there something like the following:

```
<template v-for="Dog in Dogs">
    <template v-for="Leash in Dog.Leashes">
        <span>{{ Leash.parent }}</span>
    </template>
</template>
```

Using {{ Leash }} gives me the arrays.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated here. I'll have to redo some of this once they actually get the data right, but for now, this is sort of what I'm working with.

Comment: What is `Leash.parent`? Is that mean Dog or?

Comment: @mare96 no, I'm trying to access the numbers that are the "parent" of the Leash array. I know it's a strange issue, but I can't figure it out and I need to be able to get to the values "564" and "15775" and I can't...

Comment: The leash parent means the key of the object.
`<template v-for="Dog in Dogs">
    <template v-for="(Leash, key) in Dog.Leashes">
        <span>{{ key }}</span>
    </template>
</template>`
More info: [v-for with an Object](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-object)

Comment: Try to use  in your for give index and like this:

`{{ Object.keys(Leash).indexOf(index) }}`

Comment: @CsabaGergely i think for key he will get 0,1,2 ... He need object value.

Comment: Your question isn't clear..what do you mean by 'parent'?

Comment: @mare96 You are right. In this case use this: `<template v-for="Dog in Dogs"> <template v-for="key in Object.keys(Dog.Leashes)"> <span>{{ key }}</span> </template> </template>`
To get the value simply use `Dog.Leashes[key]`

Comment: @banky he needs the key of the object "564", "15775".

Comment: While all very appreciated, each solution returns the index on the left column (0, 1, 2 etc..) of the table, rather than displaying the actual "564" and "15775". Is this to be expected and maybe I'm still not explaining what I'm after correctly? Can I even actually access and display those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access keys of your `Leash` so you need to do this:

```
        <template v-for="Dog in dogs">
            <template v-for="(Leash, name, index) in Dog.Leashes">
              <span>{{ name }} </span>
            </template>
        </template>
```

Data:

```
data() {
      return {
      dogs: [
          {
            Name: 'Gus',
            Leashes: {
              564: [
                6,
              ],
            },

          },
          {
            Name: 'Jake',
            Leashes: {
              15775: [
                457,
                787,
                278,
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
  }
}
```

I reproduce this code and in my case gives me `564` and `15775`. Is that what do you want?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this returns keys as undefined. Maybe I implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Did you try without `.indexOf(index)` or just `{{ index }}`?

Comment: I must have done something wrong the first time, it's returning the index where expected (0,1,2 etc..). Unfortunately it doesn't display the actual "564" and "15775" numbers.

Comment: Still giving the index. Thank you again for your help though.

Comment: Check my update. I reporduce it and gives me `564` and `15775` is that expected? Maybe you need do decode your json file or i dont know. @PhilT41